# Angularjs повторяет элементы внутри ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Проблема такого рода: данные внутри `ng-repeat` с использованием одностороннего биндинга при следующем рендере элемента он как-бы берет уже предыдущие данные и рендерит это. Но некоторые данные отображает правильно, а другие показывает с предыдущих элементов.

Используется версия `angularjs 1.6.5`. Cмена версии не помогает.

Это можно увидеть по `ИТОГО` в конце `Содержания` на картинке.

[image: пример]

Но, если посмотреть в `batarang scopes`, то можно увидеть такую ситуацию. 
Это данные первого ресторана, `slug` равен `annamanna99` (Объясняю, у нас  `slug` это имя ресторана).

И задаю себе следующий вопрос как так ? Имя ресторана `Annamanna99`, а отображается `cancoder` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Та же самая ситуация с другим примером.

Еще дополнительная информация: на предыдущей странице (я сделал постраничную навигацию, все загружается с сервера) и все отображается корректно.

А вот оригинальный элемент который дублируется при выводе 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепляю ссылки на код:
[order-food.component.ts](https://pastebin.com/JKr6h7fp)
[order.component.ts  - вывод заказов](https://pastebin.com/rAaiawzw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with objects track by the identifier(e.g. $index) instead of the whole object and you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones.

[сам ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398257/3945261)

Суть: при получении данных с сервера на второй странице оставались те же индексы `$index` (ибо одинаковое к-во элементов). А так как я использовал в качестве уникального идентификатора $index, то angular не перестраивал DOM потому что брал объект с уже кешированого объекта по $index ($$hashKey).